# Game Logic in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, game-engine

I am trying to program a Battleship game with different states depending on user input. I am implementing the State Design Pattern for the different types of game types, the instructions panel and other features it is going to have. My question is, when I make the JFrame for my game, should the logic be invoked during construction, or should it be during the update of the window?

For example:

```
public class BattleshipGui extends JFrame
{
  public BattleshipGui()
  {
    initizalizeFrame();
    executeLogic();
  }
}
```

The execute logic contains the game loop that changes according to the game events.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. There will be logic invoked in the beginning and throughout the game.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, the JFrame will update depending on the state the game will be in. So I want to know where the logic should be instantiated and executed. Let me update my question with an example.

Comment: Personally, they should be separate.  The "state" or "logic" should be supplied to (and independent of) the frame, this way, the GUI's only responsibility is to generate a representation of "state" or "logic"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI should only be responsible for rendering. All actual game logic should be handled on your main thread, while the EDT is painting for you (repaint posts events to the EDT). As for "invokingGameLogic", this should first never be done in the constructor (considering that method contains the loop thats updating your game). You should initFrame then start your loop dedicated to updating/rendering your game. Create an interface between updating and rendering; have variables that both rendering code and updating code can access. That way, your render code renders whatever the current state is, while update code changes it.

```
class Game extends Canvas {
    //the items used between render and update
    Player player;
    Enemy player;

    //render values
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 50, 50);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(enemy.x, enemy.y, 50, 50);
    }

    //affect values
    public void update() {
         player.x++;
    }
}
```

Keep your game logic away from your rendering. It makes programming a game easier, since you'll be able to easily find code that handles graphics, and what code handles moving players and what not.

If you are using `Component#paint(Graphics)`, then you REALLY want to seperate the game logic from rendering. Code within the paint method executes om the Event Dispatch Thread, meaning issues with updating will cause very apparent issues in GUI.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any resources where I can learn how to structure a game appropriately?

Comment: @AlanW There are books, such as  `Game Programming Patterns` or `Killer Game Progaming`, or you can just google 'java game development', and learn off some tutorials there. Your vision on the game will influence its structure, but its always good to get informed on some of the basics of game dev. Game Loop is a big word in game development, maybe you can start there